# Parse incoming x-www-form-urlencoded in nodejs

Tags: node.js, form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am using hapi for a simple API. I need to submit some data to a 3rd party api, with the data in a POST body, `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the header and the body containing the form data. I'm doing this successfully using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) and [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

I'm writing a test for this using [jest-fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) to mock the fetch service. However, the mocked fetch request is a `FormData()` object, and to get the values of the body I have to use the form-data methods, specifically `getBuffer()`. The best I can do is get the text of the form data stream, which looks like this:

```
    ----------------------------873172308964049871716608
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

    mockAuthorization_code
    ----------------------------873172308964049871716608
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

    mockAuthCode
    ----------------------------873172308964049871716608
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="redirect_uri"

    redirectUrl.com/
    ----------------------------873172308964049871716608--
```

Is there any way I can parse these to test that the correct values are being submitted?

Thanks